# How do I access the data in a POST request in express?

Tags: javascript, post, express, client, server

Here's my client side code:

```
  $.post("/audio",
    {
      type: 'instrumental',
      name: 'Instrumental_30SecondsToMars_TheKill'
    },
    function(data, status) {
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

And here's my server side code:

```
app.post('/audio', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

How do I access the type and name that I sent in the post from within the server side function?

It's definitely being called as the server is console logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the bodyparser middleware:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

and then

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parsing module like [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Use like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.post('/audio', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); // <-- now has req.body.type, req.body.name
});
```